# Expected dS/dN ratio for exome

Tags: bioinformatics, dna, mutations

I am trying to determine whether or not my sequencing data has more/less non-synonymous mutations than would be expected. My understanding is that there is some fixed ds/dn [ratio](http://pubmlst.org/software/analysis/start/manual/dsdn.shtml) for the human exome that I can use to calculate this. Is this true? And how might I calculate this?

Comment: The page linked behind the anchor "ratio" has gone stale. Can you fix that?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a fixed value for the human exome AFAIK, nor would it be a good idea to have a fixed value for the exome because different regions and genes can be under different selective pressures.

The norm is to compute the ds/dn ratio and then test against a null hypothesis of the ratio being 1 to infer if your region is under selection or not. If it is greater than 1 it indicates positive selection and if it is less than 1 purifying selection.

You can find a  decent [introductory treatment here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150319060139/http://sites.biology.duke.edu/rausher/DNDS.pdf).